# Fail Connect to Running Phoenix Applications with IEx Remote Shell at Docker

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework

Im deploy phx app using docker, running --remsh command from within the same container.

But it return could not contact remote node.

Anybody know the solution ?

Here is the snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your command, please use **--cookie** instead of **-cookie**

Comment: Thankx for the info. Yes, this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

You seem to start the application as `:nonode@nohost`. To connect to it, you should have it started with either a short or fully qualified name.

`mix release.init` creates `rel` folder with two template files in it. Check `env.sh.eex` and make sure you start a release with a short name given. This should work:

```sh
export RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION=sname
export RELEASE_NODE=<%= @release.name %>
```

---

*Sidenote:* please post everything as plain text, not as images.